# How to import dll from bin folder without adding reference in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, dll, dllimport

As in my project i used some dll by referencing in my project bin folder which only works when i paste my dll in my "C:windows/system32/mydll.dll" but when i paste my dll in bin folder and then runs my website on server it will show me error...."file not found" .
and i also used this method [DllImport("~/bin/mydll.dll")] to import it....
but it still showing me the same error "file not found"

And if i used add reference method then it shows me "Invalid COM component" error.....

please do suggest some simple and useful solution...

Answer (score 0):

Because your dll had added as `COM composant` in your reference explorer, not as simple assembly.

Nota : If you want register an assembly as COM you can use `RegSvr32 tool`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms859484.aspx

Comment: When you cilck on add reference, you select COM section

Comment: I have registeres my dll using Regsvr64 tool with the command regsvr64.exe /s MyLibrary.dll, still dll in not in the list of COM. plz help

Comment: second step use gacutil in order to register in the GAC, link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try in code:

```
    if (!Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process).Contains(HttpRuntime.BinDirectory))
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process) + ";" + HttpRuntime.BinDirectory, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```